# Hover Tab without Javascript

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm able to create tabs using Plain HTML & CSS. Respective Code is mentioned below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<style>
div.tabbed {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
}

div.tabbed > a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .5em;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #eee;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 1em;
}

div.tabbed > a + a {
    margin-left: .5em;
}

div.tabbed > a:target {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #eee;
}

div.tabbed > a > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    padding: .5em;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
    display: none;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #eee;
}

div.tabbed > a:target > div {
    display: block;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="tabbed">
    <a href="#dog" id="dog">
        Dog h jh
        <div>
            <p>This is a dog...</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#cat" id="cat">
        Cat
        <div>
            <p>This is a cat...</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#foo" id="foo">
        Foo
        <div>
            <p>This is a foo...</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#newshop" id="newshop">
        New Shop
        <div>
            <p>This is a New Shop...</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently On click event I'm able to see contents of Tab. Is it possible to get same effective on hover? [Please NOTE: I'm not using any javascript, plain HTML5 & CSS3]
Kindly suggest.

Comment: why the PHP tag? Anyway, look into the CSS3: try :hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Check this [hover tab](http://jsfiddle.net/TJtR8/4/)

```
div.tabbed > a:hover > div {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace in your CSS

- `div.tabbed > a:target` with `div.tabbed > a:hover`
- `div.tabbed > a:target > div` with `div.tabbed > a:hover > div`